# .htaccess redirect to subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that works on jQuery and full ajax (1 page design) and I'm trying to redirect the users from the root of my site `www.mysite.com` to subfolder `www.mysite.com/my/subfolder/`. I have tried the following from a past question:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} / [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my/subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It redirects properly but for some reason JavaScript is not working. Any advice?

Comment: Great set of rules! But you should remove the [NC] parts (and replace [NR,OR] with [OR] if you want to avoid the error "RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your javascript paths etc are all still valid after the url gets re-written

Comment: thanks for the fast response, you got it i have some js files referred by ../js/jsfile.js .. now should i change the folder directory to be referred by /js/jsfile.js or there is another trick in the .htaccess i can do?

Comment: @Mohammad Just change it to `/js/jsfile.js` -- that is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

This would route your page to the /my/subfolder/. It's a simplified version of what you have but works for me.